# How to call a function in c# if it has an argument?

Tags: c#

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public void onKeyDown(KeyEventArgs keyEvent)
    {
        String pressed = keyEvent.KeyCode.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(pressed); 
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        onKeyDown(args???????); // I want to call the onkeydown function
    }
}
```

So, I want to display the letter of the keyboard in a messageBox when pressed. So, to do it, I must call the function onKeyDown in the last method. How to do it ?

Comment: And in the timer event what is the key pressed?

Comment: In fact, I want to detect the key pressed...... to display it in a messageBox

Comment: you have to subscribe to onKeyEvent of contol or Form. So when key is pressed the appropriate event will fire which inturn will fire delegate which in turn will call your ethod

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171549(v=vs.110).aspx  may be useful for looking at how to handle input events as it is more wiring than executing.

Comment: It seems strange to drive your application from UI code. Is spoofing a keypress on a timer really something you want to bake into your architecture? Perhaps you might zoom out a little and tell us what you're really trying to do here.

Comment: You can pass in `onKeyDown(new KeyEventArgs(Keys.Enter));` (or some hard coded key), but you cannot *detect* what key(s) are currently being pressed.  For that, you'll have to listen to the appropriate key press events.

Comment: @MikeChristensen You could use GetKeyboardState to do that, but it doesn't seem to be what the op wants.

Comment: @JamesBarrass - Isn't that a Win32 API?  Ok, sure you could call into that.  But yea seems rather strange to go that route rather than just listen for keyUp and keyDown as they happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your form in designer view. Double Click the `KeyDown` event and write your code in the event handler. This will have an `object sender` parameter.  Which for this example you can probably ignore.

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    String pressed = e.KeyCode.ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(pressed); 
}
```

Remove the timer, it doesn't help you display a message when a key is pressed.

Comment: How to  Double Click the KeyDown event ? when i double click the textbox, it does not create textbox keydown method

Comment: @MatR select the component first with a single click. Find the event in the properties window. Double click the event you wish to code for

Comment: ok i succeded to add the method, but keyEvent when copying paste underlined in red

Comment: the name keyEvent don't exist in the actual context

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do something on both a timer and by the keypress, rather than attempting to spoof a keyboard event, place the common behaviour in a new method and then have both the key handler and the timer handler call that method.